# How to use PHP sessions or cookies to achive this?

Tags: php, cookies, session

My website is language independent, I have several language packs that I include based on user selection.

User selection form:

```
<form action='' method='POST'>
        <select name='language' onchange='this.form.submit();'>
         <optgroup>
            <option>Language</option>
         <option value='eng'>English</option>
         <option value='esp'>Español</option>
            <option value='fra'>Français</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
</form>
```

The Script:

```
 $language = $_POST['language'];

 if($language == "esp")
  include("languages/esp.php");
 else if($language == "fra")
  include("languages/fra.php");
 else
  include("languages/eng.php");
```

The problem is, when I click on a new page on the site, the chosen language is once again forgotten and loads the default English. I know I should be using cookies or sessions to keep the chosen language saved so all pages load that language pack. But how?

Comment: Why don’t you put the language identifier into your URL? If you use it as a path prefix like `/en/…` it will always be present regardless of whether the browser does allow cookies or not.

Answer (score 4):

On the top of the page:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['language']))
{
     $language = $_SESSION['language'];
}
else
{
     $language = "en";
}

include("languages/".$language.".php");
```

On the form page:

```
session_start() // assuming you haven't already done this from the above code

$languages = array("en", "esp", "fra");
if(in_array($_POST['language'], $languages))
{
    $_SESSION['language'] = $_POST['language'];
}
```

Note that `session_start()` should only be called once during the page. Normally near the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

I would use cookies though since we're talking about language selection and the user isn't likely to change his/her language choice.  With sessions, if the user closes his/her browser, the language choice is reset.  It would be similar to @Chacha102's solution except a little bit more code. You can store the language choice in the cookie by using the function

```
setcookie()
```

The cookie is then stored on the user's computer.  You can also specify when the cookie will expire.  Then you can retrieve the cookie's value (language choice) by using `$_COOKIE` (similar to `$_SESSION`).

Definitely read this:
http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have to use session_start() on every page if you want to use sessions.

Comment: As @Ondrej mentions, you will need the session_start() on each page you want to use session data on.  So, consider putting the code @Chacha102 suggests inside another included file so you are not replicating the same code all over the place.